# vector space question about span and sets

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V=IR^3 and consider the following elements of V: u_1=(1,2,0), u_2=(3,1,0) and u_3=(1,-1,1). 
Let U=< u_1,u_2> and W= < u_3>

(i) Is UuW closed under multiplication by scalars?
(ii) Is UuW closed under addition?
(iii) Is UuW a subspace of V?

I need help of all of it but I think i might have done part i, can someone just tell me if i have done it correctly please or if i need to add anything (shouldn't say 1ii, should say 1i). Also for part i, x can be in both U and W but the only way this can happen is if x=(0,0,0). Was I supposed to include this in my answer?
[image]